# Why is redux-thunk not working in Storybook?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, storybook

I have integrated the [Storybook](https://storybook.js.org/) UI development tool into my *create-react-app*.

Everything works fine until I add [**addon-redux**](https://github.com/frodare/addon-redux) as an add-on to the Storybook.

**.storybook/main.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  stories: ["../src/components/**/*.stories.js"],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app",
    "addon-redux", // This one
  ],
};
```

After I include that line, start to appear this message in my container component.

[image]

This is my container component.

**TickerList.jsx**

```js
/* eslint-disable react-hooks/exhaustive-deps */
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { handleGetTickers } from "../../../actions/tickers";
import Ticker from "../../atoms/Ticker";

function TickerList({ tickers, getTickers }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    getTickers();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="ticker-list">
      {tickers.map((item, i) => (
        <Ticker
          key={i}
          name={item.name}
          value={item.value}
          percentage={item.percentage}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    tickers: state.tickers,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    getTickers: () => dispatch(handleGetTickers()),
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TickerList);
```

This is my **handleTickers** action creator.

```js
export const GET_TICKERS = "GET_TICKERS";

function getTickers(tickers) {
  return {
    type: GET_TICKERS,
    payload: tickers,
  };
}

// handleGetTickers
export function handleGetTickers() {
  return async (dispatch) => {

      const res = await fetchData("/data/tickers.json");
      if (res.ok) {
        const result = await res.json();
        dispatch(getTickers(result.data));
  }
}
```

As we all know, we need to include the thunk to handle these kinds of actions. So I include that when creating my Redux Store. This same store imports to the Storybook also.

**store.js**

```js
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { enhancer as withReduxEnhancer } from "addon-redux"; // This is use for connect the App Redux Store with Storybook
import invariant from "redux-immutable-state-invariant";
import { createLogger } from "redux-logger";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import reducer from "./reducers";

const createMiddlewareEnhancer = () => {
  const middleware = [thunk];
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
    middleware.push(invariant());
    middleware.push(createLogger());
  }
  return applyMiddleware(...middleware);
};

const createEnhancer = () => {
  const enhancers = [];
  enhancers.push(createMiddlewareEnhancer());
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
    enhancers.push(withReduxEnhancer);
  }
  return compose(...enhancers);
};

const store = createStore(reducer, createEnhancer());

export default store;
```

Then why is it working perfectly in the browser & not only in the Storybook? Did I miss something here?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redux-thunk is a middleware, but `addon-redux` [has issues with middlewares for now](https://github.com/frodare/addon-redux/issues/24). But there also possible solution.

> If you're using redux-thunk, your React UI made be triggering actions
> where the action is a function instead of an object. Since addon-redux
> ignores middlewares, the redux-thunk middleware gets ignore and then
> an error is thrown that Redux found an action that is a function.

Answer (score 0):

In at least some cases, the [solution](https://github.com/frodare/addon-redux/issues/24#issuecomment-885979988) is in the thread referenced in the accepted answer (example uses Redux Toolkit):

> I will have to think about this one a little as it could get tricky. My gut tells me this should be fixable by changing the order of store enhancers so that addon-redux is processed after the middlewares enchancer. That way the actions would be cleaned up before getting to the addon-redux enhancer.
>
> You're right -- changing the order of the enhancers fixed it. For redux-toolkit, I did it the following way:
>
> ```js
> export const store = configureStore({
>   reducer,
>   middleware: getMiddleware(),
>   enhancers: middlewares => [withReduxEnhancer, ...middlewares]
> });
> ```